# Using quantifiers in look-arounds (R/stringr)

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds, stringr

I'd like to extract the name `John Doe` from the following string:

```
str <- 'Name: |             |John Doe     |'
```

I can do:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(str,'(?<=Name: \\|             \\|).*(?=     \\|)')
[1] "John Doe"
```

But that involves typing a lot of spaces, and it doesn't work well when the number of spaces is not fixed. But when I try to use a quantifier (`+`), I get an error:

```
str_extract(str,'(?<=Name: \\| +\\|).*(?= +\\|)')
Error in stri_extract_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
  Look-Behind pattern matches must have a bounded maximum length. (U_REGEX_LOOK_BEHIND_LIMIT, context=`(?<=Name: \| +\|).*(?= +\|)`)
```

The same goes for other variants:

```
str_extract(str,'(?<=Name: \\|\\s+\\|).*(?=\\s+\\|)') 
str_extract(str,'(?<=Name: \\|\\s{1,}\\|).*(?=\\s{1,}\\|)')
```

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Do not use `str_extract`, use `str_match` and the regex with a capturing group: `str_match(str,'Name: \\| +\\|(.*) +\\|')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:
First we remove `Name`
Then we replace all special characters with space
and finally `str_squish` it

```
Library(stringr)

str_squish(str_replace_all( str_remove(str, "Name"), "[^[:alnum:]]", " "))
```

```
[1] "John Doe"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using base R:

```
sub("Name: \\|\\s+\\|(.*\\S)\\s+\\|", "\\1", str)
# [1] "John Doe"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also use the `\K` to keep what is matched so far out of the regex match.

```
Name: \|\h+\|\K.*?(?=\h+\|)
```

**Explanation**

- `Name: \|` match `Name: |`
- `\h+\|` Match 1+ spaces and `|`
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `.*?` Match as least as possible chars
- `(?=\h+\|)` Positive lookahead, assert 1+ more spaces to the right followed by `|`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Aqje17/1) and a [R demo](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7ikSMFGV0HdLzE31UqhRgEZ1HjlZ@QpuOSnQnjqIJKrKDU9N7EkOSO1WAOoV0cByE@tKCjSUIKYEBNTExOToQ2mvPW07DXsbaF8TSUdBbCOgtSiHNsQTc3//wE).

Example

```
str <- 'Name: |             |John Doe     |'    
regmatches(str, regexpr("Name: \\|\\h+\\|\\K.*?(?=\\h+\\|)", str, perl=T))
```

Output

```
[1] "John Doe"
```

Comment: Thanks. Are `\h` and `\K` from Perl? Also, is loading the `stringr` library redundant for your answer?

Comment: @msn Yes, you are right. Those are only supported using `perl=T` and I have remove the stringr library.